# How to use MySQL's `group by` with a column that has been modified with `replace` within the select call?

Tags: mysql, grouping

I've users table (simplified):

```
id | username | url
```

I'm trying to find count of users with the same domain name, so I strip `http` text from the `url` column  through `replace` mysql function call and `group by` the stripped value but it doesn't work.

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT replace(url, "http://", "") u, count(u) c
FROM users
GROUP BY u
ORDER BY c DESC
```

I get error:

```
Unknown column 'u' in 'field list'
```

Any ideas how to run `replace` on the column and still group by the replaced values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use aliases in the `select` or `where` clause.

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

Use

```
select replace(url, "http://", "") u, count(*) c
```